# Spring Data JPA Native Query throw Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have some problem.

I have just put native query to spring jpa.

but it's throws error idk why

Here are my queries:

View create query

Using **Spring boot 1.5.2** and MariaDB 10.1.2

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `access_logs_hosts_view` AS
SELECT
    url_id,
    COUNT(0) AS access,
    IFNULL(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(referrer,'https?://',''),'/',1),'unknown') AS referrer
FROM
    access_logs
GROUP BY
    url_id
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(`access_logs`.`referrer`,'https?://',''),'/',1)
ORDER BY access DESC
```

and method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM access_logs_hosts_view ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Map<String, Object>> findCountAndReferrerByURL();
```

application.yml

```
type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

My final objective is just using one native query and get data without view.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(0) AS access,
    ifnull(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(referrer,'https?://',''),'/',1),"unknown") AS referrer
FROM access_logs
WHERE url_id = ?1
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_REPLACE(referrer,'https?://',''),'/',1)     
ORDER BY access DESC
```

Comment: You wil get a `List<Object[]>` not a list of maps.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks.